# Android Studio - IntelliJ No JDK found even though its installed and in path

Tags: intellij-idea, java-7, android-studio

I did a complete re-install of Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit today due to the fact that my computer was starting to lag on me. As you can tell from the title I am having an issue with my JDK not being recognized when I install Android Studio I got IntelliJ to install with little to NO issues at all but when I try to start a project it tells me that there is no SDK installed for that either.

Any tips to get me back up and running?

Comment: Hello, have you solve this problem. Please give your answer here if you have solved this. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually adding the JDK to the default project configuration?

You can do this by choosing `File` > `Other Settings` > `Default Project Structure` from the menu. The go under the `SDKs` heading and add the JDK by clicking the green `+` symbol and choosing JDK, the browse to your JDK folder. You can also add Android platforms here if needed.

Also, I'm not sure about this, but on my x64 system I use both a 64-bit and a 32-bit JDK. Android Studio/IntellJ uses the 64-bit (in `Program Files`) version to run, but my build uses the 32-bit JDK (in `Program Files (x86)`). Not sure if this is required, but it might be worth a shot if you are still having trouble getting it to work.